# Is stall current generally equal to inrush current?

Tags: motor, inrush-current

I haven't been able to find a clear or definitive answer on this, and I've been wondering about it for some time now:

Does the peak **inrush** current of an electric motor equal the peak **stall** current of the same motor?

In my mind, it would make sense if they're the same since, for a brief instant, the two are kinematically identical (non-rotating shaft). Is this a relatively fair assumption to make?

For example, if I don't have specifications for a motor and can determine the stall current (but don't have an oscilloscope), can I assume that the maximum inrush current will be approximately the same magnitude as the current at stall, under the same voltage? (At least in the first few seconds, before thermal effects start to complicate things, that is.)

Also, is there a rule of thumb to guess at the inrush/operating current ratio? I've heard that inrush can be up to 150% or up to 1000% of the operating current. What's the right answer? Is there one?

Comment: For a regular brushed DC motor, yes. But you don’t state which motor you are referring to? Is this homework?

Comment: @winny
No, not homework. I've just wondered for a long time (3-4 years).
I didn't specify motor type because I am curious for all types of motors. If the behaviour depends on the type of motor, I'd appreciate having a general understanding of why that is, and the most significant factors that govern such a difference in behaviour for each motor type.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to form a list of which motor types there are and if there does exist any figures for stall current of them?

Comment: I have found the odd figures here and there, but the problem is (at least in my mind) that such figures only tell the story for one specific motor model. What I've seen more-or-less confirms my theory above, but the figures I have found could simply be providng confirmation bias. I'd like the input of an EE to either confirm if my proposed explanation is correct or to upgrade my understanding on the matter. I essentially want to avoid succumbing to the Dunning-Krueger effect.

Comment: A valid approach! Please present said odd figures!

Comment: I haven't saved any of them because they weren't terribly difficult to find and I couldn't verify their usefulness. But I found them with keywords like "motor current measurement". One result that exemplifies the type of figures I've found in the past is: https://blog.arduino.cc/2012/06/15/quick-tutorial-current-sensing-for-dc-motors/; indeed, such figures have led me to theorize in the fashion explained above, as I noticed the inrush didn't seem to differ in magnitude from the stall current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial value of motor starting current is about the same as stall current for most types that are started by simply connecting directly to the power supply. Motor starting current is generally defined as the current drawn between the time that it is energized and the time that it reaches a steady operating speed. So starting really includes energization and acceleration. The starting current for an AC motor is not generally expressed as a peak current but as an RMS current variation in sub-cycle peak currents experienced during starting are generally not considered.

For a DC motor, the armature resistance determines the stall current. If 10% of the supply voltage is dropped across the armature resistance at rated load, the stall current will be 1/0.01 or 100 times the rated current. That is likely to be too much current for the commutator, so additional resistance would be inserted in series with the armature during starting. Electronically-controlled DC motors are most often limited to 150% of rated current.

Three-phase induction motors are expected to require about 600% of rated current when starting. The nameplate may be marked with a code letter to indicate the expected starting current. Starting methods that limit the current are often used for motors driving large fans and centrifugal pumps. Those methods are generally not suitable for loads that require higher starting torque. When starting current is limited, that is done to avoid causing the supply voltage to sag due to the high current. The motors are generally designed to withstand high starting current.

Motor starting current is limited for most electronically-controlled motors of all types to limit controller cost. In many cases that can be done while still providing plenty of starting torque.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I = V/R. Resistance of the motor remains the same. Either at the start, or during a stall, back-EMF is zero, hence maximum V (equal to supply voltage) & I.

Though R is imaginary for a motor, but for calculating only the amplitude of I, the real part (resistance) suffices. Therefore, resistance of the armature determines R and consequently stall/inrush I.